# Jet Engine Unrecognized Database Format

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I am trying to compact my database using vb.net and I keep getting the error message

> Unrecognized database format 'C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb'.

I have looked around and haven't found anything to help me. Here is my code

```
Private Sub Compactdb()

    Dim JRO As JRO.JetEngine
    JRO = New JRO.JetEngine

    'The first source is the original, the second is the compacted database under another name.
    JRO.CompactDatabase("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb;", "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Forte\Compactdb.accdb;")

    'Original not compacted database is deleted
    System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb")

    'Compacted database is renamed to the original database's name. 
    Rename("C:\Forte\fortedb.accdb", "C:\forte\Compactdb.accdb")

    'User notification
    MsgBox("The database was compacted successfully")

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give more information about your Access database? Which version is it created with? Does it have a password? Etc.

Comment: My access database is created with access 2010 and no password or username are required. I have trieed different versions of strings but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referenced on http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007

You can change your conn string to

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Forte\Compactdb.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When I change out the string I still get **Unrecognized database format 'C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb'**

Answer (score 0):

One of these should work

```
provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\random\myAccess2007file.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;
```

or

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\random\myAccess2007file.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;
```

Comment: Hi JapsKR, what is the difference between them? Would you please explain when to use one or another?